How to declare a RPC endpoint in the node config?
The public-addr option allows to declare the node p2p endpoint, allowing to use DNS for example, or different port than the listen port if using docker port mapping.
--public-addr <PUBLIC_ADDR>...
    Public address that other nodes will use to connect to this node.
    This can be used if there's a proxy in front of this node.

Is there a way to declare a RPC endpoint so that clients can use network discovery to list available RPC endpoints? Since there usually is a proxy for https on 443 instead of bar 9944.

I think this could help you.
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/8609
--listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333 --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30334/ws --listen-addr /ip6/::/tcp/30333 --listen-addr /ip6/::/tcp/30334/ws


No, it does not help me, I'm talking about the RPC endpoint, not the p2p endpoint.

For RPC, you can only use the --rpc-port to change the listening port I think. To perform further configuration, you should use a proxy service such as Nginx.

I know how to set the RPC port, I know how to configure a nginx proxy. I just do not know how to tell other people to use my RPC endpoint. I can hardcode this in the wallet, but this would be better to allow rpc endpoints discovery from a set of bootstrap nodes.

Well... This question just make me feel like asking how I can let others know my EVM chain ID. Currently, people rely on https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains for this information. I think this doesn't natively get supported, at least for now.

Ok, so we rely on a centralized index that can fail rather than the decentralized ecosystems we are building. It seems there is no way but to hardcode the rpc endpoints in the wallets and release a new version when this list changes. Or I can implement an offchain storage mechanism and make it available through rpc api itself.

I think your question needs more clarity, what do you want to achieve? If you want to be reachable by a ssl enabled dns address you will need a proxy, see here for instructions. It is not possible without since the rpc cannot handle ssl. With a proxy you can use any domain/port combination you want which can be internally proxied to the local rpc port.

Ok, I'll try to explain further. I did set up a proxy and tls certificate, my node RPC endpoint is reachable with a url lik wss://mynode.example.com or multiaddress: /dns/mynode.example.com/tcp/443/ws. I want a client connected to the network to be able to discover my RPC endpoint automatically using the nodes network layer. In other words, I'm trying to achieve for RPC endpoint the same thing that's done for p2p endpoint.
